# Grouping rows by value templates

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any option to automatically group rows by their values if they fit certain criteria or template?
For example I want to group all iOS 14* records into one and all Android 8* into other

[image]

Plus group 5 records with smallest number of users into one.

[image]

---

**Source data**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Android 10 | 4259 |
| iOS 14.6 | 4067 |
| Android 11 | 1818 |
| Android 9 | 1562 |
| iOS 14.4.2 | 1016 |
| Android 8.1.0 | 458 |
| Android 8.0.0 | 348 |
| iOS 14.4 | 341 |

---

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Android 10 | 4259 |
| iOS 14.6 | 4067 |
| Android 11 | 1818 |
| Android 9 | 1562 |
| iOS 14.4.2 | 1016 |
| Android 8.1.0 | 458 |
| Android 8.0.0 | 348 |
| iOS 14.4.2 | 341 |
| iOS 11.4 | 1 |
| iOS 12.1.3 | 1 |
| iOS 12.4.2 | 1 |
| iOS 13.2 | 1 |
| Android 7.0.0 | 1 |

---

Comment: https://superuser.com/ would be the more appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There are several ways to do this, you might use a Pivot Table, the Query function using complex formulas. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: You can help those here to help you by sharing a link to a spreadsheet with the raw data already entered (what is shown in the post images should be sufficient) as well as a manually entered expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be resolved by using `query()`. There are precdeents on webapps and stackoverflow for each element of the solution but none for bringing them together into a single formula

**OS USERS - iOS14 and ANDROID 8 GROUPED**

Use this formula:
`=query({query({A2:B9},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B9},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B9},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc")`

This consists of several nested queries:

**Group Android 8 Users**

- `=query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B9},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)})`

**Group iOS 14 Users**

- `=query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B9},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})`

**Group users who are neither Android 8 or iOS14**

- `=query({A2:B9},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ")`

---

[image: group 1]

---

**OS USERS - iOS14, ANDROID 8 AND SMALLEST 5 USERS GROUPED**

Use this formula:
`=query({array_constrain(query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc"),count(query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc"))-B17,2);query({"Other",sum(array_constrain(query({query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc")},"select Col1, Col2 order by Col2 asc"),B17,2))})})`

This also consists of several nested quesries. To enhance flexibility, the number records with smallest number of users is treated as a variable. In this example, the number of smallest values is entered in Cell: B17

**All user groups, iOS14 & Android 8 aggregated**

- `=query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc")`

**The total number of user groups**

- `=count(query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc"))`
- uses `COUNT()`.

**All user groups sorted ascending, array_constrain = 5**

- `=array_constrain(query({query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc")},"select Col1, Col2 order by Col2 asc"),B17,2)`

**Sum the total of the smallest user groups**

- `=sum(array_constrain(query({query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc")},"select Col1, Col2 order by Col2 asc"),B17,2))
- uses `SUM()`

**All users, iOS14 & Android 8 aggregated, array_constrain =  (total-5)**

- `=array_constrain(query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc"),count(query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc"))-B17,2)`

**Sum of the 5 smallest User groups**

- `=query({"Other",sum(array_constrain(query({query({query({A2:B14},"select Col1, Col2 where NOT Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' and NOT Col1 matches  '.*Android 8.*' ");query({"Android 8 *",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*Android 8.*' label sum(Col2) ''",0)});query({"iOS 14.*",query({A2:B14},"select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '.*iOS 14.*' label sum(Col2) ''")})},"order by Col2 desc")},"select Col1, Col2 order by Col2 asc"),B17,2))})`

---

[image: Group2]

---